ARMv4: Does reading PC with a "shift by register" operand really offset it by an additional 4 bytes?
Section 4.5.5 of the ARMv4 docs read (my emphasis):

4.5.5 Using R15 as an operand
If R15 (the PC) is used as an operand in a data processing instruction the register is used directly.
The PC value will be the address of the instruction, plus 8 or 12 bytes due to instruction prefetching. If the shift amount is specified in the instruction, the PC will be 8 bytes ahead. If a register is used to specify the shift amount the PC will be 12 bytes ahead.

To test whether this is the case, I put a little program together:
    MOV     r0, pc 
    ADR     r1, label1
    SUB     r2, r0, r1
    MOV     r3, #1 
    MOV     r4, pc, LSL r3
    ADR     r5, label2 
    SUB     r6, r4, r5 
stop:   
    B       stop
label1: 
    MOV     r0, r0
    MOV     r0, r0
label2:
    MOV     r0, r0
    MOV     r0, r0

Now, playing with a few online emulators of ARMv7 (I couldn't find any online emulators for ARMv4) such as cpulator and VisUAL, I noticed that both of these have the final state r4 = 0x30, which would imply that PC was 0x18 at the instruction MOV r4, pc, LSL r3 (a mere 8 bytes ahead and not 12).
If PC was indeed 12 bytes ahead, I would expect r4 = 0x38, being (0x18 + 4) << 1.
Is this behaviour ("reading PC shifted by a register will be 12 bytes ahead instead of 8") a quirk of ARMv4 that was gone by the time ARMv7 came around? I thought that something like this might be kept consistent between ARMv4 and ARMv7 because of how easily observed the difference is, but perhaps it was ironed out?
Or am I misunderstanding the ARMv4 docs?

Nice presentation and an interesting question, but it sounds to me like being about some emulator implementation, so best might be to address either maintainer. Also, ARMv4 was produced way into the naughties, so kinda modern. Regarding the description, I'd read it like you do

It's not really about the emulator implementations. Having seen that the behaviour in two ARMv7 emulators are the same, I'm inclined to think that's correct behaviour in ARMv7 but not in v4. This would be a nice opportunity for someone to weigh in on how this "feature" disappeared between v4 and v7. Also, many ISAs are still in use today, despite their heyday having been in the distant past. I've also seen ARMv4 questions on this SE before.

@jogloran True. For example, "Zilog announced the discontinuation of the Z80 in April 2024 after nearly five decades of production." and nobody disputes that the Z80 counts as retro.

Is there a reason not to believe the ARMv4 manual? Also ARMv7 manual says it's always plus 8 in ARM mode and always plus 4 in Thumb mode which you saw with the emulators. Is this enough for an answer?

This change would have broken binary backward compatibility. Were breaking changes otherwise common or expected between ARM ISA versions?

For what it's worth, on a Raspberry Pi Model 1B (ARMv6), the shifted value is 8 bytes ahead for either an immediate or a register shift.  So it's not just your emulator; physical hardware does it too.  Doesn't answer whether ARMv4 had the +12 behavior, though.  Did you check what earlier ARM versions were documented as doing?

@jogloran The problem is that your who argument is based on some emulator and how that one seems to act. Therefore questions about the emulator behaviour need to go to the creators/programmers of that software. Also, any real silicon test can be done against any later ARM, as this is a fundamental behaviour, any change would be breaking software, so have you tried?

Check some GBA emulators or hardware - the GBA uses ARMv4 (don't be confused by the fact that it has an ARM7 cpu, that's an unrelated numbering scheme).
mGBA, for example, going by the source, indeed increments the PC register value by an extra 4 in the register shift case.
Most likely, this is indeed an ARMv4 quirk that was removed in later versions, perhaps because they determined that there weren't enough executables that would be both affected by this and expected to run on ARMv6+ without recompilation.

Also, continuing that thought, taking the PC and shifting it by a variable amount (or any amount, really) is probably not an instruction generated by most compilers - that's also probably why they may've felt confident in doing this breaking change, perhaps after analyzing how many binaries truly have this instruction.

I have an HP50G calculator whose CPU is ARMv4T. I can try to test this on it at some point.

@NateEldredge: I recall this binary incompatibility problem between v3 and v4. I visited Acorn NZ in 1994 or 1995 to test an Apple II emulator a friend and I wrote. We developed it on the A5000 (ARM3) and it broke on the new Risc PC models (ARM 6XX/7XX). It was the core 6502 instruction execution branching to a handler address shifted by the 6502 opcode in a register. The prefetch change from 8 to 12 bytes is what I recall. Sorry it's just an anecdote. Related questions etc

Which kind of "ARMv4 docs" is meant here, precisely? I'm looking into DDI0100E, and there's no even 4.5.5 chapter. The only mention of 12 bytes there is in 2.4.3, stating that STR and STM would store either PC+8 or PC+12 value, implementation-defined.

Also, that PC+8/12 feature is a purely HW quirk, due to specific organization of pipelining in specific processors (and that stuff going into arch specs always causes misunderstanding and a forever-lasting extra implementation effort, obviously). So I believe that no simulator would simulate it exactly as also there is no sense in checking this stuff on armv7 cpus. The only viable way is to get armv4 cpu in your hands and check there.

@lvd The docs are ARM DDI 0029E. Strangely this isn't available anywhere official, but it can be found easily by Googling the paragraph I quoted.

As the OP stated in the comments to his question, the mention of '12 bytes for shift amount' came from ARM7TDMI datasheet, DDI0029E (see page 58). I was unable to find there any mention of "ARMv4" architecture, so I guess that the whole ARM7TDMI product had been created before they officially introduced their ARMvnumber architecture generations.
I was able to find ARM DDI 0100B dated back to 1996, right after the introduction of the ARM7TDMI product. On the page 128 (3-90 by embedded numeration) there's a notion for a 'shift by register' operand:
Use of R15: Specifying R15 as register Rm, register Rn or register Rs has
UNPREDICTABLE results.

In a (relatively) fresh ARMv7a specs on page 475 there's also a similar description for shifts by register values:
Encoding A1
 ARMv4*, ARMv5T*, ARMv6*, ARMv7
LSR{S}<c> <Rd>, <Rn>, <Rm>
...
d = UInt(Rd); n = UInt(Rn); m = UInt(Rm); setflags = (S == ‘1’);
if d == 15 || n == 15 || m == 15 then UNPREDICTABLE;

Some conclusions and guesses:

I guess that the ARM7TDMI had basically 3-operand (2 source and single destination) structure of its pipeline/ALU, while the 4th operand (that is, shift amount from a register) was kind of afterthought and it was taken from regfile/bypassed from following pipeline stages into the ALU a cycle later.

The whole attitude of "reading PC always gets you PC of the instruction plus 8" assumes that the actual PC the instruction was fetched from is not carried along with the decoded instruction down the pipeline, but instead is taken directly from incrementing PC counter two stages of pipeline earlier, since the "+8".

Combining p.1 and p.2, we naturally would get PC+12 value for register shift amounts.


Later during formal architecture specifications, ARM team might have decided to cover those implementation quirks which had already differed from a general "PC+8" approach under the 'UNPREDICTABLE' label.

Yes, this is the behavior of the ARM920T ARMv4T core on the Samsung S3C2410A on a hardware HP 50g graphing calculator, circa 2006.
Using HP-GCC 2.0 I ran the following code.
main.c
#define TINY_PRINTF
#include <hpgcc49.h> //the standard HP lib

extern void shift_pc_reg(unsigned *actual, unsigned *result);
extern void shift_pc_imm(unsigned *actual, unsigned *result);

int main(void){

    clear_screen(); //clear the screen

    unsigned actual, result;
    shift_pc_reg(&actual, &result);
    printf("Reg:\nactual %x\nresult %x\n",
       actual, result);
    shift_pc_imm(&actual, &result);
    printf("Imm:\nactual %x\nresult %x\n",
       actual, result);

    WAIT_CANCEL; //loop until ON pressed

    return 0;
}

pc-shift.s
.arm
.text
.global shift_pc_reg

shift_pc_reg:
    mov r2, #0
label_reg:
    mov r2, pc, lsl r2
    str r2, [r1]        @ result
    adr r2, label_reg
    str r2, [r0]        @ actual
    bx lr

.global shift_pc_imm
.global label_imm
shift_pc_imm:
label_imm:
    mov r2, pc, lsl #0
    str r2, [r1]        @ result
    adr r2, label_imm
    str r2, [r0]        @ actual
    bx lr

The output is:
Reg:
actual 122023c
result 1220248
Imm:
actual 1220250
result 1220258

However, on ARMv6 (Raspberry Pi 1 Model B, with a ARM1176JZF-S  ARMv6 core on the Broadcom BCM2835 SoC), it shows an offset of 8 for both versions:
Reg:
actual 104a0
result 104a8
Imm:
actual 104b4
result 104bc

